# Why does $\mu X .\langle a\rangle X$ not make any sense in $\mu$-calculus?

Tags: logic, computer-science, modal-logic

I've been reading up on [modal $\mu$-calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_%CE%BC-calculus) via this paper "[The mu-calculus and model-checking](https://www.labri.fr/perso/igw/Papers/igw-mu.pdf)" to get a better intuition for fixed-point logic.

In the paper, the authors state that the formula $\mu X .\langle a\rangle X$ "is just false" but I don't really understand why. From what I see, $\mu X .\langle a\rangle X$ could mean that "there is a finite sequence of $a$-transitions".

Can you please point out, what I am missing? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the easiest way to see this is using the approximation approach outlined on page 5:
$$\mu^0X.\langle a \rangle X = \emptyset$$
$$\mu^1X.\langle a \rangle X = \langle a \rangle \emptyset = \emptyset,$$
so we have already reached a fixpoint, and hence $\left[\!\left[ \mu X.\langle a \rangle X \right]\!\right] = \emptyset$. In other words, the formula holds in no states, which is what is meant by a formula being false.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, thank you :)